# JNLP error, code shown is different not as it is in my JNLP

Tags: java, netbeans, jnlp, sign, codebase

This is the JNLP file showed in pop-up-error after launching application. I know where is the problem - on line 21 there is no slash. But this file was far ago changed and i uploaded it on to server and refreshed everything but it is always showing me this old file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://fuuu.sk/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>PocketBrain</title>
    <vendor>zatokar</vendor>
    <homepage href="www.fuuu.sk"/>
    <description>PocketBrain</description>
    <description kind="short">PocketBrain</description>
</information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="PocketBrain.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eclipselink.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b.jar">
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="model.BrainInPocket">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

This is my new JNLP file which is everywhere already but still in error is shown the old one.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://fuuu.sk/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>PocketBrain</title>
    <vendor>zatokar</vendor>
    <homepage href="www.fuuu.sk"/>
    <description>PocketBrain</description>
    <description kind="short">PocketBrain</description>
</information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="PocketBrain.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eclipselink.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar"/>
<extension href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="model.BrainInPocket">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

And here is the jnlcomponent1.jnlp:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="" href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>jnlpcomponent1</title>
    <vendor>ECLIPSE_</vendor>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <jar href="lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b.jar" 
        download="eager"/>
</resources>
<component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

That's it. Before when i ran it with the new files there was a problem with this extension (jnlpcomponent1.jnlp). The error was showing me: problem with $$codebase it could not find path: //fuuu.sk/$$codebase/lib/org.eclipse.persistence..... even though as you can see in both my codebases is http://fuuu.sk/ so why that error?

I already searched about it again and here is the same question: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/294505-java-jnlp-file-error-shows-code-that-isnt-in-my-jnlp-file/ and it is not answered. 
BTW: I removed everything from ftp, i restarted my PC to be sure that I don't have it in any temp memory but nothing happened still the same code which is not in any file.

Comment: Try uninstalling the App. from the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) before re-launching it.

Comment: Yes i already wanted to answer the question with this answer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/problemsindex.html (last problem on this webpage) helped ;) put answer so i can mark it thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson but here is another question about the same program if you would like to answer i would be very happy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175937/jnlp-error-code-shown-is-different-not-as-it-is-in-my-jnlp?noredirect=1#comment30087891_20175937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling the App. from the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) before re-launching it.   While JWS is great at updating resources referred to in a JNLP, it is ..less great at updating the JNLP itself.

Comment: Yep, java caches applets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this for the completeness (I'm using windows 7 x64):
@Andrew Thompson's answer really fixed my problem: I signed my jnlp jar files (both main jar and jar libraries), then I re-cleaned and re-built my jnlp app. But when trying to launch my jnlp I got the `"ExitException jnlpcomponent1.jnlp not found"`.

So I went to Start Menu->Programs->Java->Configure Java-> "Genral" tab (well I'm using the spanish windows 7, so I went to Inicio->Todos los Programas->Java->Configurar Java->Pestaña "General").
Then, in the "Internet Temporary Files" section (sección "Archivos Temporales de Internet" in spanish) I clicked the button "Delete Files" ("Suprimir Archivos"), then I chose to delete and uninstall everything.

At last I re-cleaned and re-built my jnlp app. It works now :D